# How to Prove the following complex inequality

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

I'm Really struggling on where to go with this proof which says the following:

Prove that, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$
$$\left|z\right| \le \left|\mathrm{Re}(z)\right| + \left|\mathrm{Im}(z)\right| \le \sqrt
{2}\left|z\right|$$

Some examples to show that either inequality may be an equality as well would also help a lot.

Comment: Do you know the triangle inequality?

Comment: I'm trying to get to use it better but my lecturers keep saying it during explanations and I'm still unsure on how to use it efficiently. I do have this in my notes though, $||z_1| - |z_2|| \le |z_1 + z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|$

Answer (score 2):

We need to establish

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le|a|+|b|\le2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Now square each of them and validate

Comment: I've gotten something like: $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{y^2}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ but that gives me $2|z|$

Comment: @M.Turner, But $$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: sorry, I'm still new to the mathjax. Now look at the edited comment and that's what I wanted to say.

Comment: @M.Turner, Now square each of them

Comment: That'll give me,

$$x^2 + y^2 \le \left(\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{y^2}\right)^2 \le \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2.$$

Now what? This looks to be worse.

Answer (score 1):

Note that triangle inequality gives
$$|z|=|\text{Re}(z)+i\text{Im}(z)|\leq |\text{Re}(z)|+|i\text{Im}(z)|=|\text{Re}(z)|+|\text{Im}(z)|.$$
To see the second inequality, note that
$$2|z|^2-(|\text{Re}(z)|+|\text{Im}(z)|)^2=|\text{Re}(z)|^2+|\text{Im}(z)|^2-2|\text{Re}(z)||\text{Im}(z)|=(|\text{Re}(z)|-|\text{Im}(z)|)^2\geq 0.$$
Thus
$$2|z|^2\geq(|\text{Re}(z)|+|\text{Im}(z)|)^2,$$
take square roots on both sides yield the result.